# WCF REST Starter Kit has ugly URIs

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

This starter kit seems to use incredibly ugly URIs that include a "Service.svc" filename.

Surely if you're going to have a service called say "Users.svc" you'd want the URI to look like '/users/' rather than '/Users.svc/'?

Is there a way this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of hosting the WCF REST Service in IIS - for the time being, this requires a *.svc file and that file shows up in the URL.

You do **not** have this limitation:

- if you [self-host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx#id0070063) - create a NT Service or a console app and instiate and open a "WebServiceHost" inside it - you can pick your service URL at your liking
- if you can wait 'til .NET 4 in March 2010 - it will have ["file-less" activation in IIS (search for "File-less Activation (no .svc)" in the linked article)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx), e.g. you can define *.svc-less services

Marc